# C# Fast matrix modification

Tags: c#, matrix

I have a list of sorted double values. [100.3, 100.7, 101.1, ..., 4000.2].

I have a `Matrix<double>` of size 4096 * 4096 containing values

For each values of the matrix, I would like to take the index of the closest value in the sorted list and replace the current `matrix[i,j]` value with this index.

So far I have this:

```
//Fill list from file
List<double> valueList = new List<double>();
string[] dataLine = File.ReadAllLines(listDataPath);
foreach (string line in dataLine)
{
    valueList.Add(float.Parse(line.Replace('.', ',')));
}


//Create 4k matrix with values between 1000 and 3000 for example
int rows = 4096;
int columns = 4096;
var rand = new Random();

Matrix<double> mat = new(rows, columns);
Parallel.For(0, rows, i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        mat[i, j] = 1000f + (double)rand.NextDouble() * 2000f;
});

Stopwatch cs = new();
cs.Start();

Parallel.For(0, rows, i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
         double newValue = valueList.BinarySearch(mat[i, j]);
         mat[i, j] = newValue;
    }
});
cs.Stop();
MessageBox.Show(cs.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

It take about 1 second to perform this operation. I've already use `Parallel.For` and `BinarySearch`. Is there something more efficient ?

Comment: What is that `Matrix` class? Is it something you wrote? And if so, don't you think it's pertinent to see it when you're scrounging CPU cycles for something that takes 1 second?

Comment: Just a note about your use of `BinarySearch`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-8.0 `BinarySearch` returns an `int` not a `double` because it's returning the index of the searched value. If it's an exact match it's a positive index that's returned, but if it's not an exact match it returns a negative value that is the two's compliment of the insertion index that you can get by using the `~` operator.

Comment: Can you please add a [mre] with some sample data so it can be run and tested a bit easier?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `BinarySearch` and doing `Parallel.For` over each row is about as fast as you can hope for in the generic case. The only way you could optimize this to go faster is if there is something known about the list that you are searching or the data in the matrix that you could exploit to short circuit something in your search logic.

When optimizing something like this it's good to take a quick look at how long your processes are taking on average and see if it makes sense for that process to go faster than it already is.

If you are searching every cell of a matrix that is 4096 x 4096 that's 16,777,216 searches that have to be made. You are saying it's taking about 1 second to do that many searches, so on average each search is taking about 60 ns. 60 ns is very very fast, so you have to ask yourself, is it reasonable to improve the search speed much faster than 60 ns?

By doing a quick high level calculation like this, it's easier to see that you are trying to shave nanoseconds off of a 60 ns operation, which may not be possible, and really the main reason it's taking so long is just the size of the number of searches. If you are wanting to speed things up, your best option may be to try to limit your number of searches. You say this is image data, so maybe you can do this process on just a subsampling of cell locations that would essentially be running it at half or maybe a quarter of the original resolution, but whether or not you can do that will be based on what you are trying to accomplish in the end.

Answer (score 0):

So first, a few remarks about your code in general:

1. As I mentioned in my comment, there is no standard `Matrix<T>` type in .NET. As such, I can only assume that you wrote it, and probably not well. I'd throw it away if I were you and stick to plain arrays until you get more comfortable with .NET.
2. Binary search. Theoretically a good tool in this case, but the .NET implementation spends a lot of time checking for nulls (I just profiled it). Even so, with a `valueList` array of 50000 elements, a plain linear search outperformed it by a factor of 10. Sometimes brute force is just better!
3. The binary search method you used doesn't return the index to the closest element, it returns either the index of the exact value you asked for, or a negated two's complement representation of the index of the first largest value after it. You need some math to get an index to that (`~value - 1`) and to consider array bounds (it will give an invalid value in that case).

As such, this simple code runs on my machine in ~100ms:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 50000).Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();
var mat = new double[4096 * 4096];

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Parallel.For(0, 4096 * 4096, index => mat[index] = FindClosestIndex(Random.Shared.NextDouble()));
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

double FindClosestIndex(double searchedValue)
{
    var bestIdx = 0;
    for (var idx = 1; idx < values.Length; ++idx)
        if (values[idx] > searchedValue)
            break;
        else
            bestIdx = idx;
    return bestIdx;
}
```

You can then load the resulting array into your custom `Matrix` class if you want.

Comment: Your `FindClosestIndex` is very efficient because it's given a best case scenario every time it searches. `Random.Shared.NextDouble()` always returns a value 0 to 1, and you are searching an array 0 to 50000, so the matching index is always found at the very beginning of the array. If you multiplied your random value by 50,000 you would find that it's a lot less efficient at finding the matching index.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to me

1. This function is part of an image processing project. Matrix come from `Emgu.CV.Matrix`, it's a C# wrapper of the library openCV.


2&3. For me it was the best choice due to log(n) complexity, I didn't know that .Net make all this checks.

Sometimes the simplest code is the best

Comment: To put some numbers to my comment from before, I thought it would be good to run a benchmark on your `FindClosestIndex` vs a `BinarySearch` using the same size `values` array, but benchmarking over 10,000 operations instead of 4096 x 4096 operations. Testing as is where the search value is always 0 to 1 `FindClosestIndex` averaged 39.7 us and `BinarySearch` averaged 112.7 us, but if you multiply the random by 50,000 `FindClosestIndex` averaged 38,379 us and `BinarySearch` averaged 228.7 us, which means under a more typical search space `FindClosestIndex` is 167 times slower than `BinarySearch`